# Recovering deleted Cassandra DB files

Tags: cassandra, datastax, data-recovery

I screwed up massively, and accidentally deleted some SSTable (.db) files from a Cassandra data directory.  Literal "rm -rf" style deletion.  I've been trying to recover them using foremost, but I need to know the header and footer file signatures for SSTables in order to configure foremost to do the job.

Does anyone know the header/footer file signatures?

Or, can someone give me some ideas on how I can go about recovering these?

Comment: Presumably if you're running Cassandra you have replicas on more than one node. Do you have RF > 1? If so, the data could be restored via repair.

Answer (score 0):

Are they in your snapshots directory? Cassandra creates hardlinks to sstables in the snapshots directory precisely for this kind of scenario.